# Pre-Populate HTML form file input

Tags: html, forms, file-io

I have a VBScript that goes over an HTML form, fills it with fixed values and then submit it. It works fine so far, but now i need to set the location of a file that is going to be uploaded within the form data.

I believed if I set the location on the value it was going to work, but it doesn't.

```
 <input type='file' name="file_field" value='file_location'/>
```

Also, I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535263%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#properties) while researching. It says...

**input type=file**
*Value: Sets or retrieves the displayed value for the control object. This value is returned to the server when the control object is submitted*.

Is there a way (by code) to fill that input, even with jQuery?

Comment: That would be a bit of a security issue if you could change/prepopulate a user's file input fields. So no, you cannot do this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

No. This is not possible.

Browsers block against setting the value attribute on input of file type for security reasons so that you can't upload a file without the user's selected any file himself.

Comment: As for sure you can add only preview close around of this input with already uploaded file. This one is useful for image uploads.