# How to attach a file to html 'file' element for upload with jquery/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html element we are trying to attach a file to:

```
<input id="uploaded_file_file_for_upload" class="file optional" type="file" name="uploaded_file[file_for_upload]">
```

User already selects a file for the element above. What we need to do is to remove the current file selection and attach a new file to it. The new file is an image file and is saved in a `canvas` element. Here is the js code for new file:

```
 function resize(image, width, height) {
      var mainCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      mainCanvas.width = width;
      mainCanvas.height = height;
      var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
      alert(width + '    resize to    ' + height);
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
  .....(remove current and attach the new file to the elelment#uploaded_file_file_for_upload)
   };
```

We tried the following to attach and it did not work:

```
$('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').attr('src', mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
```

The problem may be that it is not an image element. What's the right way to remove and attach a file type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre-Populate HTML form file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841147/input-file-to-array-javascript-jquery/ . Not possible to alter to `FileList` object . Try converting `FileList` object to array, using `.splice()` to remove file from array , insert new file , `POST` array containing new file object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't. The only way to upload a file is to ship the file selected by the user, with no change.

The only way to do exactly what you are trying to do here is using :

- a native app
- a hybrid app with native plugin
- via a browser plugin (flash, chrome app...)

Unless, the browser security policy will block you.

Two workarounds could be:

- send the original file and resize it server side (php library, nodejs...)
- or resize the image as you want, then uploading the base64 encoded image data of the edited image via a POST ajax request to your server, and then write it to a file server side.

Comment: Resize on client side has less bandwidth cost and offers better customer experience. It is harder to implement compared with service side solution.

Comment: `Remi Becheras`, is text field good to store base64 encoded image data for upload?

Comment: text field seems ok for the base64 encoded data which is a string.

Comment: Yes, send it as a simple string. Its a string representation of an image.