# how to upload images with Angular js ? or how to use / simulate ng-model in input type file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, input, angular-ngmodel

I have a form wich contain name, email... and user's image for a web app registration, i send data via a rest api with $http in a objet called userData, how ca i add to this objet the file / image ? how to use angular model or bind the file to a scope variable ?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: An answer to a question I've asked: [Pre-Populate HTML form file input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input#answer-16367121)

Comment: its not about prepopulating the image, it is the user who will do it, its about binding uploaded file to a ng-model .

Comment: didnt get it, do you want to send the file to the server? do you want to upload to s3? what do you want to do?

Comment: @Jony-Y i want to send the file to my server ( laravel backend ), but i would like to send it in the same objet with the other input element (name, lastname, tel, email..etc)  but ng-model does not work with file input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ng-file-upload: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

It works well with images and supports uploading by drag and drop, multiple files etc.