# Laravel retrieve physical file instance onto input file

Tags: laravel-5

is there a way to retrieve physical file and apply into the input file field. Like assigning the $file onto it? It appears during update method of my controller keeps triggering the request validation error because its empty.

```
{!! Form::file('doc_upload', $file, ['id' => 'doc_upload']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, browsers do not let you prefill file fields.

> Browsers block against setting the value attribute on input of file
>   type for security reasons so that you can't upload a file without the
>   user's selected any file itself.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input)