# Make input type of file settable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set an image in file input (HTML input file type) without using the input up-loader (set the file programmatic).

I have found useful links about using the clipboard and data transfer but it is not working on Internet explorer.
There is any solution that can be used in Internet explorer?

```
var dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData ||new DataTransfer(); // specs compliant (as of March 2018 only Chrome)
dT.items.add(new File(['foo'], 'programmatically_created.txt'));
inp.files = dT.files;
```

Comment: Have you reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854392/attach-file-to-input-type-file-with-javascript) post?