# can we access the image name in input type file in php?

Tags: php

```
 <image id="output" width="300" height="170" />
  <input type="file" name="name" accept="image/*" value="<?php echo 
  $row['image']; ?>">
```

In this, we will create an input type file where we will upload a profile image but we want to get the image name during the update section so can we get the image name in the input type file using the value tag?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand you, but do you mean you wish to have a uploaded filename to be displayed in the input field?   Has this file been uploaded?

Comment: yes I have to get the image name on the input field

Comment: Yes, you can. Just query the image location and echo it. The way you did, it should work fine. You can show the error if you are having any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre-Populate HTML form file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input)

Comment: the `file` input is read-only. If the value is already stored in the db, use a hidden input for the existing file name