# how to autofill the input field with file type if I submit the form without other fields?

Tags: laravel, forms, file, crud

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" 
        value="{{ old('name')}}" />
    @if($errors->has('name'))
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name')}}</span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    <textarea name="description" id=""  rows="4" class="form-control">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
    @if($errors->has('description'))
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('description')}}</span>
    @endif
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Image</label>
     <input type="file" name="file"  class="form-control"  >
    
    @if($errors->has('image'))
        <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('image')}}</span>
    @endif
</div>
```

how to autofill the input field with "file" type if I submit the form without other fields?

I tried to find the solution of it online but I could be able to find the solution .Is it any way to auto fill the "file" type input field or there is no way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pre-Populate HTML form file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input)  (There are many others as well...)

Comment: What for exactly? To upload it again? (Since that seems to be an image you could show the image below the file upload if it has already been uploaded)

Comment: There isn't a built-in way to "prepopulate" an `<input type="file"/>` input; this is an interface for uploading a file from the User's system, and it would be a huge security hole if your browser could set the `value` for that... Typically, you can do `value="{{ old('file') }}"` (as you're doing), but the `type="file"` input doesn't support that at all. You'll need to either A) make the User upload the file again, or B) do _something_ with caching/session, where the uploaded file is cached or stored in memory so the User doesn't need to upload it again, or C) something completely custom.